# Acknowledgement/Dedication problem

Tags: front-matter

For my thesis, after my title page (1st page), on the next few pages I want to put a

page 2: dedication

page 3: acknowledgement

I tried using the `\begin{dedication}\end{dedication}` and `\begin{acknowledgement}\end{acknowledgement}` commands but it does not work, so I guess I dont have the package or I need to define a new environment?

How would I go about adding a dedication/acknowledgement similar to the image below?

[image: some image]

Currently my code is roughly as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{titling} % for useful adjustments to the titles
\usepackage{url} % for simple url formatting
% command to make the course info
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myinfo}[2]{
  \gdef\@myinfo{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \textit{E-mail:} & \url{myemail@email.edu}\\
  \textit{Course:} & #2\\
  \textit{Professor:} & #1
  \end{tabular}
  \par\vspace{12pt}
  \textsc{University}}
}
% add the extra information after the date
\postdate{\par\vspace{12pt}\@myinfo\end{center}}
\makeatother

\title{\textbf{Course Name}}
\author{My Name}
\myinfo{Professor Name}{Stats} % provide course and prof info
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't really need an environment for this kind of thing.  You can add

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\par\vspace*{.35\textheight}{\centering Dedicated to my parents\par}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
A lot of people helped me.
```

This will format the acknowledgements page like a chapter, but it won't appear in the table of contents, which is probably what you need.  Alternatively, you can just format the `Acknowledgements` page manually, in which case you would do it similarly to the dedication page (with a `\clearpage` before it.)