# Add a quote to a blank page centered

Tags: blank-page

I would like to start my thesis with a blank page with a quote of a famous scientist.
I however do not find an elegant way to create the following in a estecially pleasing way (a larger font, stylish quotes). 
Key points: Insert blank page with quote centered both vertically and horizontally.

"Quote"
Author 1955

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acknowledgement/Dedication problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45809/acknowledgement-dedication-problem)

Comment: Maybe I should add that I am using documentclass{book}

Comment: @GijsHompes I've updated my answer. Now you don't have to manually calculate the width of the `\parbox`; I've also added another options based on **barbara beeton**'s comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The style chosen will depend heavily on the style you're using for other elements of your document (for example fonts, page layout, sectional units formatting), so it's difficult to produce a "universal solution". Here's one possibility; I chose not to center it vertically but to use the double of space below the quote than the space above it; the width of the `\parbox` is calculated as the width of the longest line of the quote (stored in the length `\longest`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newlength\longest

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill

\settowidth\longest{\huge\itshape just as his inclination leads him;}
\centering
\parbox{\longest}{%
  \raggedright{\huge\itshape%
   A man ought to read \\ 
  just as his inclination leads him; \\
  for what he reads as a task \\ 
  will do him little good.\par\bigskip
  }   
  \raggedleft\Large\MakeUppercase{Samuel Johnson}\par%
}

\vfill\vfill

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

**babrbara beeton** suggested to place the author flush right as it's often used in epigraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newlength\longest

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill

\settowidth\longest{\huge\itshape just as his inclination leads him;}
\centering
\parbox{\longest}{%
  \raggedright{\huge\itshape%
   A man ought to read \\ 
  just as his inclination leads him; \\
  for what he reads as a task \\ 
  will do him little good.\par\bigskip
  }   
  \raggedleft\Large\MakeUppercase{Samuel Johnson}\par%
}

\vfill\vfill

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: consider setting the author flush right (`\raggedleft`).  it will "square off" the block and make it a little easier to identify the author of the quotation.  this approach is often used with epigraphs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added this option to my answer. I initially proposed the non-flushed option since I wanted to emulate the style used by Michael Spivak in his *Calculus*.

Comment: this is certainly subjective, so showing both possibilities is good.

Comment: This worked well for me, but only after I placed it in the "dedication" environment described here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11011

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,csquotes,setspace}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} %%remove showframe in your document
%
\makeatletter
\def\nobottom{%
\def\@texttop{\ifnum\c@page>0\vskip \z@ plus 3fil\relax\fi}
\def\@textbottom{\ifnum\c@page>0\vskip \z@ plus 2fil\relax\fi}}
%
\def\resetopandbottom{%
\def\@texttop{\ifnum\c@page>0\vskip 0pt plus .00006fil\relax\fi}
\def\@textbottom{\ifnum\c@page>0\vskip 0pt plus .00006fil\relax\fi}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\nobottom
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{displayquote}[\upshape\bfseries Author 1955][---]
\onehalfspacing\Large\itshape
\lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
\clearpage
%
\resetopandbottom
\pagestyle{headings}
%
\lipsum[1-10]
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions given worked as a charm, I however chose for the first option, pure for aesthetic reasons. 
Implementing this in LaTeX is straightforward. Implementing this in LyX is a tad less straightforward, hence the steps needed to achieve this effect:

1. Hit CTRL+L (insert latex code) and add `\null\vfill`
2. Insert a frameless box and set it's inner box to Parbox by using the
   settingswindow.
3. In the parbox hit CTRL+L again and insert `\raggedright{\huge\itshape%`
4. Type your quote
5. CTRL+L:`\par\bigskip}`
   `\Large{author}\par%}`
6. Jump out of the box and below the parbox add
   these lines (again CTRL+L) `\vfill\vfill` `\clearpage`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry in advance for that demand, I'm still learning...

First solution works well. I use it also at the beginning of my report. Instead of at the frontpage, I put it just after a few pages.

However, text written afterwards is also centered, which is not suitable.

Does anyone know how to get back to the previous configuration (which was justified for me?)

EDIT : I find the solution, easy of course...

I just used the package **ragged2e** and wrote \justify just after \clearpage.

The text is afterwards correctly justified, as it was before.