# Inserting a quote onto the (otherwise blank) left-hand-side page of a book

Tags: quoting, thesis, front-matter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a quote to a blank page centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57263/add-a-quote-to-a-blank-page-centered)

I am writing a thesis in `\documentclass{book}`. I wish to insert a quote on the blank page that comes after my preface and before my first chapter.

How might I go about doing that?

Comment: This question has been posed and answered very resent. You can find a solution here : [Add a quote to a blank page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57263/add-a-quote-to-a-blank-page-centered/57305#57305)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say much about how the quotation should be styled, so my suggestions below are rather generic in nature. The MWE (minimum working example) also assumes that your preface takes up only one page; please indicate if this is not the case.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % package that provides filler text
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty} % optional -- suppress showing of page number
\begin{quotation}
\em % optional -- to switch to emphasis (italics) mode
\lipsum[2]

\medskip
\raggedleft
by Lipsum 
\end{quotation}
\vspace*{\fill}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

See resulting output below:

[image][image]

Comment: great, thank you! Is there an ideal way to get the quote to be in the center of the page?

Comment: @martin: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you have in mind regarding "an ideal way to get the quote to be in the center of the page"? Should each line of the quote be centered individually, or do you just want to narrow down the width of the text block? (By the way, the `quotation` environment already uses a measure that's narrower than `\textwidth`.)

Comment: I don't think that I want either of those options (but I am not sure...). I would like for the entire quote (that is the block of letters that make of the quote) to be physically placed in the center of the page. I guess I could do this by inserting a lot of \\ \\ \\ .... but that seems stupid.

Comment: Thanks for providing more details. I've edited the MWE to include a  pair of `\vspace*{\fill}` instructions at the top and bottom of the code for the quotation page. The spacing quantity `\fill` is "infinitely stretchable" (in TeX jargon); inserting these instructions at the top and bottom of a page forces all remaining material to be vertically centered.